# Spring MVC - Gravar Dados em TXT

Tags: java, spring

Como poderia fazer pra dentro de um controller Receber dados via Post (no Spring MVC) e gravar estes dados em um TXT?

Posteriormente, na Model abrir este TXT e enviar para View.

Alguem teria algum exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Crie um metodo no seu controlar que receba uma requisição tipo post com os dados que deseja salvar como parametro. Crie um TxtDAO para o CRUD que deseja realizar em cima desse txt. A requisição entrega para o controller que entrega para o dao, este aplica a ação que você quer e te retorna o resultado. Na verdade eh a mesma analogia que faria em um DAO para banco de dados, soh que no conector, ao invés de ter um banco de dados, você construiria o DAO para arquivo.